# Cudd Package : Binary decison diagrams

Tags: binary, binary-decision-diagram, cudd

Can anyone point some good material on Cudd package. I am looking for some concise matter here. The one at http://vlsi.colorado.edu/~fabio/CUDD/ doesn't seem to give a good introduction to the matter. Any video lectures relating to BDD and its application are welcome.

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 4):

See Knuth's [Computer Musings](http://scpd.stanford.edu/knuth/index.jsp) for video lectures covering the basics as well as many varied applications:

- [Fun With Binary Decision Diagrams (BDDs)](http://myvideos.stanford.edu/player/slplayer.aspx?coll=ea60314a-53b3-4be2-8552-dcf190ca0c0b&co=18bcd3a8-965a-4a63-a516-a1ad74af1119&o=true)
- [Fun With Zero-Suppressed Binary Decision Diagrams (ZDDs)](http://myvideos.stanford.edu/player/slplayer.aspx?coll=ea60314a-53b3-4be2-8552-dcf190ca0c0b&co=af52aca1-9c60-4a7b-a10b-0e543f4f3451&o=true)

Answer (score 3):

[1] introduced ordering in binary decision diagrams, [2] summarizes well the implementation techniques used in practice, [3] is the default reordering algorithm in CUDD, [4] is an introduction that doesn't assume any particular background, [5] is quite detailed and mathematical (by Somenzi -- the author of CUDD), and [6] is another, quite excellent, self-contained, and applied introduction to the topic.

[1] Randal E. Bryant
"Graph-based algorithms for Boolean function manipulation"
IEEE Transactions on Computers
Vol. C-35, No.8, August, 1986, pp.677--690

[2] Karl S. Brace, Richard L. Rudell, Randal E. Bryant
"Efficient implementation of a BDD package"
27th ACM/IEEE Design Automation Conference, 1990
pp.40--45

[3] Richard Rudell
"Dynamic variable ordering for
ordered binary decision diagrams"
IEEE/ACM International Conference on
Computer-Aided Design, 1993
pp.42--47

[4] Christel Baier and Joost-Pieter Katoen
"Principles of model checking"
MIT Press, 2008
section 6.7, pp.381--421

[5] Fabio Somenzi
"Binary decision diagrams"
Calculational system design, Vol.173
NATO Science Series F: Computer and systems sciences
pp.303--366, IOS Press, 1999

[6] Henrik R. Andersen
"An introduction to binary decision diagrams"
Lecture notes for "Efficient Algorithms and Programs", 1999
The IT University of Copenhagen